# generating axis2 webservice client jar

Tags: java

I have generated axis 2 webservice client in my eclipse project named "client:.My webservice client works fine.Now what i am doing is exporting this project as `client.jar` (using export as jar feature of eclipse)

Then i included client.jar in classpath of Test project.
So inside Test.java when i try to use following code i get a compile time error.

```
 MyStub stub = new MyStub();
```

Error is:

```
The type org.apache.axis2.AxisFault cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

What i am trying to do is giving out my client.jar to any one who can use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have Axis2 JAR in your classpath. Edit you JAR manifest or include this JAR file into the Test project dependencies.